# Why hasn't the Centralia fire been starved to death?

Tags: united-states, disasters

The infamous [Centralia coal mine fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralia_mine_fire) has been burning for approximately 60 years now.  Googling "why hasn't the Centralia fire been put out" gives plenty of results for why it would be infeasible to pour enough water or other anti-flammable material in there to extinguish the fire, but I don't see anything addressing a much simpler solution: *just starve it of oxygen.*

Unlike the ["Gates of Hell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darvaza_gas_crater) in Turkmenistan, the Centralia fire is burning deep underground.  As every schoolchild knows, a fire needs three things to burn: fuel, heat, and oxygen.  So it feels like it shouldn't be particularly difficult to address the oxygen side of the equation: pour some concrete and seal off the mine from surface access, and let it use up the oxygen from the air that's already inside there.  Boom, no more fire.  Give it a while to cool down afterwards so you don't get a [backdraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdraft) upon unsealing it, and the problem should be solved.

But in over half a century, this hasn't happened, so I assume there must be a good reason why not.  What am I missing?

Comment: A question quite similar I asked myself, quite often indeed. (Strange thing going on there) But is this really H:SE material? Or some other SE? Please emphasise why this is HistorySE and not (OngoingStupidEvents:SE, EarthScience, or sth)?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Because the fire is a historical event and it felt like a better fit than Physics.SE.

Comment: Yo, PhysicsSE might be one other avenue! But to better align this here (technicalities): how about asking "immediately", "Soon" (vague, I know) with a cut-off date? (To remove all recent events aromas…?)

Comment: The problem is the actual *question itself* isn't much about history. I'd probably second the suggestion of [Earth Sciences](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/), although I don't post there so I don't know for sure what their exact scope is. I'd imagine the answer has to do with the feasibility of plugging up every possible source of oxygen for an entire mountain-spanning cavern network. I'd think people knowledgeable in mining (and perhaps coal) could answer that easier than people knowledgeable in history.

Comment: OK....reading up on it, it looks like such attempts *were* made, so we can talk historically about those I guess.

Comment: One possible way to narrow this question down is to clarify what kind of answer you are expecting. Are you asking for a summary of historical attempts to put the fire out? Are you asking for a scientific justification for why typical firefighting techniques do not work? Are you asking for an explanation of why politicians don't seem to be willing to spend more money on this?

Answer (score 4):

What can be said historically is that [some attempts at smothering the fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralia_mine_fire#Early_remediation_attempts) were made. About 6 months after the fire began, a contractor attempted to "flush" the fire along its expansion route by mixing crushed rock with water, which indeed would have the effect of preventing oxygen to chemically combine with the coal (aka: "burn") in that area. This was still fairly early on, involved 10,000 cubic yards of material, and turned out to not be enough.

About 9 months later another project tried surrounding the area of the fire with incombustible material, then another flush attempt, and then yet another "total and concerted" flushing attempt at roughly twice the expense of the first. They all failed.

At this point the fire appears to be burning over an 8-mile stretch, so any attempt to duplicate the smothering effort that was made early on would likely have to be far more invasive, and involve orders of magnitude more smothering material.

Comment: Historically: yes, that's 'an answer'. But I keep wondering: _why_ wasn't _this_ smothering (like x,y) enough? And that keeps on feeding the move2 b[Other:SE?] suspicion? (Alternative routes of oxygene supply, whatnot?)Missing are tghe technical explnations — even if _contemporary_ to the hist-angle?

Comment: @LаngLаngС - From reading through things, it looks like its just really really difficult to find *all* the spots that are on fire. I highly doubt its even possible to fill in the *entire* cavern system. But details about these kinds of things are the kinds of questions that really ought to go over to the Earth Sciences site.

Comment: I'm not asking about "smothering" the fire with large amounts of material, but rather about using small amounts of material to seal off exits to the surface, such that no more oxygen can flow in to continue fueling the flames.  The fire dying out wouldn't be immediate, but it feels like wouldn't take *decades* either.

Comment: @MasonWheeler ... and how do you know where all those "exits" are? One steaming hole they found only because it ended up directly under a highway.  But again, if that's your question, we probably aren't the place to go for expertise on making cave systems airtight.

Comment: @MasonWheeler That's perhaps the problem: the actual structure with _all_ of its exits seems quite complex (not counting deep oxygen sources, some not requiring access to 'above ground weather'). Thus: abetter approach might be a 'now present analysis' (on WhatnotSE), Than a H:SE listing of 'tried this, failed'?